# Hot to enable live reload on docker-compose for Airflow?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

This is probably a duplicate, but couldn't find it here - if yes, sorry for that.

I have a simple docker-compose Airflow app with `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  postgres:
    ...
  init:
    ...
  webserver:
    ...
  scheduler:
    ...
```

How can I enable live reload, so that I can quickly develop `scheduler` service?

Comment: do you mean refresh of dags automatically ?

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In airflow.cfg look for those parameters :

Number of seconds after which a DAG file is parsed. The DAG file is parsed every
`min_file_process_interval` number of seconds. Updates to DAGs are reflected after
this interval. Keeping this number low will increase CPU usage.

```
min_file_process_interval = 30
```

How often (in seconds) to check for stale DAGs (DAGs which are no longer present in
the expected files) which should be deactivated.

```
deactivate_stale_dags_interval = 60
```

How often (in seconds) to scan the DAGs directory for new files. Default to 5 minutes.

```
dag_dir_list_interval = 300
```